# Como colocar o scroll de um elemento a esquerda

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Normalmente quando se usa `overflow-y: scroll` ou `overflow-y:auto`, a barra de rolagem aparece à direita do elemento.

```css
.scroll-me{
   height: 80px;
   width: 200px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-me">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
                
                
<br>
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </div>
```

Eu porém preciso colocar um determinado elemento alinhado à direita e, portanto, desejo que a scrollbar aparece à esquerda.

Como eu posso fazer isso com css?

Answer (score 4):

Usa [`direction: rtl;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/direction) que é a diretiva que indica que o conteúdo deve ser interpretado da direita para a esquerda. Em algumas linguas escreve-se da direita para a esquerda e esta é a norma.

Se for caso disso podes dar esta diretiva no elemento que tem o scroll e depois dar de novo `direction: ltr;` no elemento interior para restaurar o nosso stardard.

```css
.scroll-me {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-me">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.


  <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, gostei, interessante. Mas teria como fazer sem o texto alinhar a direita?

Comment: Não funciona no safari

Comment: @WallaceMaxters junta `text-align: left;`

Comment: Novidade algo não funcionar no Safari :p

Comment: hehehehehe, é vero, só para constar a compatibilidade